# How to pass arguments to a robot library

Tags: robotframework

it seems as if in "Robotframework" a class is instantiated when it is defined as Library.
I do this:

> ```
> Library       /home/johann/xmlSockets.py   "./config.xml" "test"
> ```

In python, the class can be instantiated:

```
> class xmlSockets():
>     def __init__(self, configfile, Suchliste):
```

and there is no problem. With python it is working flawless.

When it try this in robotframework:

> [ ERROR ] Error in file
> '/home/johann/robotest/Tests/fuenf.robot' on line 6:
> Initializing library 'xmlSockets' with arguments [ "config.xml" | test
> ] failed: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '"config.xml"'

I tried config.xml, "config.xml", 'config.xml', './config.xml', "./config.xml,  @{config.xml device}...

no success.

Comment: Where do you think "./config.xml" should point to?  Are you assuming it's the same folder as the test? Same folder as xmlSockets.py? Or do you expect it to be the current working directory?

Comment: Hello Bryan, i´ve described the solution beath: robotframework search under "Test" subdirectory, i have to supply the right absolute directory or relative from "Test" directory then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that you are adding quote marks to the name of the file. The error message isn't telling you that `config.xml` doesn't exist, it's telling you that `"config.xml"` doesn't exist. So, the first step is to remove the quotes:

```
Library       /home/johann/xmlSockets.py   ./config.xml  test
```

The second may be because you're assuming the library is looking in the same folder as the library rather than in the current working directory. In this context, "." represents the current working directory, which may not be the same as the directory with the robot file, nor the directory with the python file.

In a comment you said the config file is in the same folder as the robot file. If that's the case, I recommend you use the [built-in robot variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#built-in-variables) `${CURDIR}` to pass the full path to your library:

```
Library  /home/johann/xmlSockets.py   ${CURDIR}/config.xml  test
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution ist, that the current directory is NOT the directory with the Library (or python class), it is under this in the test directory. So we must navigate BACK to the place where the python class was imported (or other) weith "../config.xml" or the take absolute path to the file.

Comment: Your terminology is a bit weak. Robot has a variable named `${CURDIR}` (an abbreviation for "current directory") but that is not the same as the _current working directory_. The latter may or may not be under the test directory.

Comment: ${CURDIR} is the Test-Subdirectory.

Comment: Yes, I know. What I'm saying is that your use of "current directory" is vague. Some might interpret that to mean the current working directory rather than `${CURDIR}`.

Comment: Bryan, the "current working directory" is sometimes abbreviated as "CWD" while the ${CURDIR} in robotframework is point to the "Test"-subdirectory as i wrote. Regards

Comment: You are missing my point completely. Your answer uses the words "current directory". It is ambiguous. It is unclear if you mean cwd, ${CURDIR}, the current working directory, or the current directory where the test is located.

Comment: No, I understand your point completely. I'm just letting you know that your answer is ambiguous, and I've explained why it is ambiguous.

Comment: Dear Bryan please read my answers: where have i used the term "current working directory"? Maybe you confused something? I wrote: " 0

The solution ist, that the current directory is NOT the directory with the Library (or python class), it is under this in the test directory. So we must navigate BACK to the place where the python class was imported (or other) weith "../config.xml" or the take absolute path to the file".

Comment: _"where have i used the term "current working directory"? "_ I never said you did. I said you use the term "current directory" which is an imprecise term. It's not clear if you mean "current working directory" or if you mean the directory pointed to by `${CURDIR}`, or something else.

Comment: Bryan, you said, as an answer to me: "Your terminology is a bit weak. Robot has a variable named ${CURDIR} (an abbreviation for "current directory") but that is not the same as the current working directory." Why do you doubt my answer with "but that is not ... current working directory" when i´ve never said something about the "current working directoy"? This doesnt make sense

Answer (score 0):

If the library is in the same project as the config.xml you can use ${CURDIR} variable from [built-in-variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#built-in-variables).
the current directory will be the directory of the file where you create the library. I would use this to specify the library path as well. Something like this:

```
Library       ${CURDIR}${/}path to lib${/}xmlSockets.py   ${CURDIR}${/}path to config${/}config.xml   "test"
```

Comment: "...the current directory will be the directory of the file where you create the library": No Jiri, that would not work.  ${CURDIR} is pointing to the Test directory.

Comment: perhaps my description is very poor, but I am pretty shure it works because i use in this way, it is "An absolute path to the directory where the test data file is located" not test directory, but test data file, meaning the file where you import the library. So it does not depend on where you execute the test, and it is not an absolute path, in case you clone the repository on different machine, etc.

Comment: You don't need to use `${/}` - a simple `/` will work on all platforms and is much easier to read.